# get property on view in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mvc4 c# razor web application.
Is it possible to add a property that will be available from views ?

like "User" of System.Security.Principal .
I can start write in view code the following :

```
@if(User.Identity) ... bla bla bla
```

I have a class:

```
public class UserModel
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

now I have a property in BaseController class named "UserInfo" that all controllers inherit from.
the code :

```
public UserModel UserInfo
{
    get {
        if (_userInfo == null)
        {
          ...fill user info
        }
        return _userInfo;
    }
}
```

I don't want to pass it as the @model but still to be possible to use it on the view
@UserInfo how can I do it ?

Comment: You could use the ViewBag, but is there a reason you don't want to add it to the model?

Comment: 1.I have a lot of views and don't want to add every model
2.I don't like ViewBag cause it is dynamic. is there a way to implement it like when you have on the view to "User" property ?